# Having issue on loading complex attributes data into array of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of element that has some data attributes. I am able to load single data attributes to an array of array `dataAraay` but on `data-size` which is like group of arrays in string format I don't know how to load them into the `dataArray` to exactly looks like

```
dataArray = [
        ["1","true","X1","48","14","139", "android"], 
        ["1","true","X1","49","15","135","51","15","140","ios"],
        ["1","true","X1","49","800","135","51","200","140","52","14","141" "windows"]
]
```

How can I fix this?

```js
let dataArray = [];

$(".data").each(function(){
dataArray.push([ $(this).data('number'),
            $(this).data('avaiable'),
            $(this).data('brand'),
            // I have issue here on loading the zies into each array
            $(this).data('app')
          ]);

});
console.log(dataArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data" data-number="1" data-avaiable="true" data-brand="X1" data-size="[48, 14,139]" data-app="android" ></div>
<div class="data" data-number="3" data-avaiable="false" data-brand="M200" data-size="[49,15,135],[51,15,140]" data-app="ios" ></div>
<div class="data" data-number="5" data-avaiable="true" data-brand="T500" data-size="[49,800,135],[51,200,140],[52,16,141]" data-app="windows" ></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can surround the `data-size` attribute value in brackets, after which you can `JSON.parse` it to get an array of arrays from it. Then, flatten the array, and cast the size items to strings:

```js
const dataArray = [...$(".data")].map(({ dataset }) => {
  const { number, avaiable, brand, size, app } = dataset;
  const flattenedStringSize = JSON.parse('[' + size + ']')
    .flat()
    .map(String);
  return [number, avaiable, brand, ...flattenedStringSize, app];
});
console.log(dataArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data" data-number="1" data-avaiable="true" data-brand="X1" data-size="[48, 14,139]" data-app="android"></div>
<div class="data" data-number="3" data-avaiable="false" data-brand="M200" data-size="[49,15,135],[51,15,140]" data-app="ios"></div>
<div class="data" data-number="5" data-avaiable="true" data-brand="T500" data-size="[49,800,135],[51,200,140],[52,16,141]" data-app="windows"></div>
```

Also, if possible, fix the spelling of `avaiable`, else it may likely cause confusion for future readers of the code.

Using `Array.prototype.map` and `dataset` makes the inclusion of jQuery nearly pointless - you may switch out the `$()` call with `querySelectorAll`, and you'll be able to remove the dependency on an external library entirely:

```js
const dataArray = [...document.querySelectorAll(".data")].map(({ dataset }) => {
  const { number, avaiable, brand, size, app } = dataset;
  const flattenedStringSize = JSON.parse('[' + size + ']')
    .flat()
    .map(String);
  return [number, avaiable, brand, ...flattenedStringSize, app];
});
console.log(dataArray);
```

```html
<div class="data" data-number="1" data-avaiable="true" data-brand="X1" data-size="[48, 14,139]" data-app="android"></div>
<div class="data" data-number="3" data-avaiable="false" data-brand="M200" data-size="[49,15,135],[51,15,140]" data-app="ios"></div>
<div class="data" data-number="5" data-avaiable="true" data-brand="T500" data-size="[49,800,135],[51,200,140],[52,16,141]" data-app="windows"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Certain Performance is correct and much better than the following answer, however the following answer in my opinion is **much easier to understand** to a basic programmer.

This code does what you were doing (I pushed the `data-app` at the end, since that's how you wanted), except it has a really long line right after the big `.push()`. What that line does is

1. It gets the `size` data
2. Converts it from an array to a string
3. Replaces all the brackets so it becomes a string in which all the "sizes" are separated by commas
4. Splits the string on the comma to make it an array with **ALL** of the size values
5. Loops through that array and pushes the current value into `dataArray`

And of course, at the end, it pushes the `data-app` to make it into the order you wanted.

```js
let dataArray = [];

$(".data").each(function(i) {
  dataArray.push([$(this).data('number'),
    $(this).data('avaiable'),
    $(this).data('brand')
  ]);
  $(this).data('size').toString().replace(/[\[\]]/g, '').split(",").forEach(e => dataArray[i].push(e));
  dataArray[i].push($(this).data('app'));
});
console.log(dataArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data" data-number="1" data-avaiable="true" data-brand="X1" data-size="[48, 14,139]" data-app="android"></div>
<div class="data" data-number="3" data-avaiable="false" data-brand="M200" data-size="[49,15,135],[51,15,140]" data-app="ios"></div>
<div class="data" data-number="5" data-avaiable="true" data-brand="T500" data-size="[49,800,135],[51,200,140],[52,16,141]" data-app="windows"></div>
```

**Side note:** This wouldn't affect anything in your code, but as Certain Performance mentioned in his answer, please change the spelling of `avaiable` to `available` (the correct spelling). It makes it much less confusing to people who read your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution using `concat` method.

```
let dataArray = [];

    $(".data").each(function(){
              var size = $(this).data('size').toString();
              size = size.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '').split(',');
                var item = [ $(this).data('number').toString(),
                $(this).data('avaiable').toString(),
                $(this).data('brand'),
              ].concat(size);
    item = item.concat($(this).data('app'));
    //console.log(item);
    dataArray.push(item);

    });
```

```js
let dataArray = [];

$(".data").each(function(){
          var size = $(this).data('size').toString();
          size = size.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '').split(',');
            var item = [ $(this).data('number').toString(),
            $(this).data('avaiable').toString(),
            $(this).data('brand'),
          ].concat(size);
item = item.concat($(this).data('app'));
//console.log(item);
dataArray.push(item);

});
console.log(dataArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data" data-number="1" data-avaiable="true" data-brand="X1" data-size="[48, 14,139]" data-app="android"></div>
<div class="data" data-number="3" data-avaiable="false" data-brand="M200" data-size="[49,15,135],[51,15,140]" data-app="ios"></div>
<div class="data" data-number="5" data-avaiable="true" data-brand="T500" data-size="[49,800,135],[51,200,140],[52,16,141]" data-app="windows"></div>
```